# How to delete 1000 separator from CSV file columns when using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm handling a CSV file with several columns and rows. The values in my CSV file are integers with 1000 separator like 99 999 and 87 222. I'm trying to calculate mean values but I'm getting an error `Exception has occurred: DataError No numeric types to aggregate`and I'm pretty sure it is because of the 1000 separators in my values.

`data = pd.read_csv('newdata.csv', sep = ";", skiprows=[0], skipinitialspace=True)`

That doesn't fix my problem. I have also tried `data["First title"] = data["First title"].str.strip()` for every column but that didn't work either.

Better ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried something like `df.astype()` ? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pandas [read_csv method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) has a "thousands" optional parameter, which you could use to indicate what this thousands separator is.

Hence, you can use something like

```
df = pd.read_csv('newdata.csv', sep = ";", thousands = ' ')
```

to handle your data input.